# How to run TestNG Tests on Octopus

Tags: java, rest-assured, octopus-deploy

I wanted to run my TestNG and RestAssured test cases written in Java to be run in Octupus Deploy, so that when the code is checked in using Team City and deployed using Octopus, my java classes starts running.The developers are writing their development code using C# and deploying using Octopus.

I tried searching the internet but couldnt find any helpful resource

Comment: Can some one help me here, I need it urgently.

Comment: please provide more info, what was tried, which issues you experienced. Also in the 1st place why use Octopus Deploy to run test cases?